# CSS and Nested tables

Tags: html, css, nested, css-tables

I have html table that contains multiple other tables.   My problem is that the inner tables inherit the same rules as the outer table.

Is there a way to over ride the rules of the outer table?   I basically want to tell the inner table:

Hey inner table Your name is "X".  I want you to forget all about your outer table and its rules.   I want you to follow these other specific rules.

IS there a way to make that happen in HTML/CSS?  Examples?

Comment: Your best bet would be to learn how to create page layouts with CSS and `<div>`'s instead of nested tables.  It's the proper way layouts are done now.

Comment: I hate maintaining old code that is full of nested tables ><;

Comment: `table {/*rules*/}` and `table table {/*other overriding rules*/}` that's how it's done?

Comment: What rules are you talking about? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Sparky even today (2.5 years later), some data is still tabular. And now and then one has to deal with data that has more than two dimensions. Also, the OP's problem gets neither better nor worse when the markup is e.g. `div.outer > div.row > div.cell > div.inner > div.row > div.cell` instead of `table.outer > tr > td > table.inner > tr > td`.

Comment: @peterp, you twice missed the ***"layouts"*** qualifier in my comment.  That means I wasn't talking about any of the OP's "tabular" data.  Regardless, if you just have have tabular data, you're probably not needing to nest the tables.

Comment: @Sparky no I didn't miss it, I just wondered how you came to the conclusion that the OP was talking about layouts and needs to learn how to use CSS with divs.

Comment: @peterp, my last comment should have been clear:  _"Regardless, if you just have have tabular data, you're probably not needing to nest the tables."_  In other words, if you're not tabulating data, you're doing a layout.

Comment: That's a matter of interpretation I guess, mine is different. But thanks for clarification :)

Comment: @peterp, when tabulating data, the content of a table cell would be data... not another table.  Not really sure how that's open for various interpretations, but to each his own.

Comment: Well, that assumes that the contained data is an atomic value, why shouldn't it contain a more complex data structure? Imagine a table containing developers per language per country. Maybe you want to break the devs further down by gender and age. That would be a table within a table, and it would be semantically correct, IMHO.

Answer (score 25):

```
table.something > thead > tr > td,
table.something > tbody > tr > td,
table.something > tfoot > tr > td,
table.something > tr > td {
   ...
}
```

This will ensure that only direct children of the selected table, and not of nested tables, will receive the styles.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you have the following

HTML

```
<table class="outer-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="inner-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        I'm some content!
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS - Without class/ID**

```
table { border: 1px solid black; }
table tr td table { border: 1px solid green; }
```

Sometimes you can get away with:

```
table { border: 1px solid black; }
table table { border: 1px solid green; }
```

**CSS - With Class/ID**

A little note with Classes and IDs. Classes are something that can be applied to as many elements as you desire and carry the styling specified. IDs should only be used for one element, as this is an identification to that element. That means if you have two nested tables, you need to give that second table a new unique ID.

ID's are shown as # in CSS. So if you just want to use it for the specific ID, it will be:

```
#outer-table { /* Outer table Style */ }
#inner-table { /* Inner table Style */ }
```

Using the class (as the example shows) in CSS, is a period. If you use the period without specifying the element, it will be used for all elements that have a class of the same name, so it's best to specify what element you want it attached to.

```
table.outer-table { /* Outer table Style */ }
table.inner-table { /* Inner table Style */ }
```

Comment: What's wrong with assigning classes and/or id's to the tables instead?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with assigning classes and/or IDs to the elements, it's recommended! Although, I've worked on a few projects where we were not able to modify the markup in any way. Just modify the external stylesheet. I was just assuming things (3am >.<)

Comment: I am starting to see the pattern.  Although I intend to use class names at the minimum.  What does `table table { format stuff; }` look like when class names are applied?

Comment: That would be simply <table class="myclass">...</table>. Then your CSS would be table.mycalss { /* style */ }. I'll add this to the answer so you can see how it is.

Comment: @cumbo's advice is wise. i made these examples last night; they're the same table, once just got alot more depth than the other, you can see exactly what's going on there. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/bMZfv/        http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/bMZfv/13/
they aren't nested tables, so that's why this is a comment and not an answer; regardless, you can easily target them exactly like this.

Comment: I ran into a problem similar to this. I found that the order of entry in the CSS is important. I had my inner-table declared before my outer-table. Therefore when I analyzed the rendering in IE 9 I saw the out-table style was the last added. I the HTML I declared the outer than the inner. In the CSS I declared the inner than the outer. It was the declaration order in the CSS that led to my rendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is class and id. Be sure to use the element.

```
table.outter { some: style; } /* class */  
table#inner { some: style; } /* id */
```

You can also use

```
table { some: style; }  
table table { some: style; } /* override outter table */
```

or combine the two

```
table.outter { some: style; } /* class */  
table.outter table#inner { some: style; } /* id */
```

Hope this helps.